# Matlab code example for piecewise linear approximation and Euler Equation Iteration

Tags: macroeconomics, computation, software

Where I can find a good Matlab sample code that performs Euler equation iteration with piece-wise linear approximation of policy functions?

The Projection method I have in mind is something like described in the Finite Elements method in Aruoba, Fernandez-Villaverde, Rubio-Ramirez (JEDC 2006) or more generically Chapter 4 in Heer and Maussner "Dynamic General equilibrium models" (the examples in the cited references are either Fortran or Gauss).

Comment: Where have you tried looking? What did you search for?

Comment: Searched mainly on web-resources of textbooks or scholars online shared resources. Need it to learn the method within a simple framework (like stochastic growth model) to apply it to an open-economy bigger model.

Comment: When you say Euler equation iteration, what specifically do you mean? I can think of a few different Euler equation type methods... Could you maybe link to a paper (or book/notes) that explains what you have in mind?

Comment: If you mean by 'euler equation iteration' reverse shooting as in Judd (1998, §10.7) I could provide a deterministic continous time example. Projection method does not ring a bell.

Answer (score 2):

Two suggestions:

First, try some of the sample code at [this website](http://www.vfitoolkit.com/). It builds simple Euler equation iteration methods from scratch in Matlab.

Second, try the sample code [here](http://www.simonmongey.com/teaching--notes.html). You will need to read the associated notes, also. The code makes use of the CompEcon toolbox in Matlab, by Miranda and Fackler (associated with their book:  Applied Computational Economics and Finance).

Answer (score 1):

I wrote some simple Matlab code which solves a stochastic optimal growth model via Euler function (Coleman policy) iteration, and then again with value function iteration. You can find [here](https://github.com/Flintro/Coleman-Iteration).

I uploaded it because I also noticed that basically the only other source of code for this stuff is QuantEcon.